# Counting the frequency of words in a list with a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I want to count the frequency of each unique string in a list and then append the results to a list of dictionaries, saving the string as the key and the value as the frequency of the string.

An example would be:
input:

```
word_list=["I","am","bob","I","am","hungry"]
```

output:

```
dict_list=[{"I":2},{"am":2},{"bob":1},{"hungry":1}]
```

---

```
word_list=["I","am","bob","I","am","hungry"]
dict_list=[{"placeholder":0}]

for word in word_list:
    for i in range(len(dict_list)):
        if word not in dict_list[i].keys():
            dict_list.append({word:1})
            break
        elif word in dict_list[i].keys():
            dict_list[i][word]+=1
            break

dict_list.pop(0)
print(dict_list)

#outputs is [{'I': 1}, {'am': 1}, {'bob': 1}, {'I': 1}, {'am': 1}, {'hungry': 1}]
#instead of [{"I":2},{"am":2},{"bob":1},{"hungry":1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:-**

```
word_list=["I","am","bob","I","am","hungry"]
hashmap={}
for word in word_list:
    hashmap[word]=hashmap.get(word,0)+1    
print(hashmap)
```

**Output:-**

```
{'I': 2, 'am': 2, 'bob': 1, 'hungry': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
from collections import Counter

out = [{k:v} for k,v in Counter(word_list).items()]
# or
# out = [dict([x]) for x in Counter(word_list).items()]
```

Output: `[{'I': 2}, {'am': 2}, {'bob': 1}, {'hungry': 1}]`

But honestly, what is the point of breaking a dictionary into a list a single item dictionaries?

The output of `Counter(word_list)` is far more useful:

```
Counter({'I': 2, 'am': 2, 'bob': 1, 'hungry': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a list comprehension to generate the result in one line like so:

```
from collections import Counter

word_list=["I","am","bob","I","am","hungry"]

dict_list = [{key: value} for key, value in Counter(word_list).items()]

print(dict_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'I': 2}, {'am': 2}, {'bob': 1}, {'hungry': 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import `Counter` from `collections` and set up a `Couter` for your `word_list` then convert it into a `dict`:

```
from collections import Counter

dict_list=Counter(word_list)

dict_list=dict(dict_list)

print(dict_list)
```

**Output**

```
>>> {'I': 2, 'am': 2, 'bob': 1, 'hungry': 1}
```